# How to Parse XML into JSON Array?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

How to Parse XML into JSON Array?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: can't you just tranform your XML to array in PHP and then `json_encode()`it ?

Comment: I've tried with many possible build-in functions of php, nothing helped the need. Then I jumped on the above way. Throwing error in the line **$xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement($test->soapenvBody->qdeinvoke->qdelosRequest->xsddata);**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution:

```
if (!function_exists('xmlToArray')) {
    function xmlToArray($xmlInput, $bodyXpath) {
        $response = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $xmlInput);
        $xmlTest = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
        $body = $xmlTest - > xpath('//soapenvBody')[0];
        $simpleXml = json_decode(json_encode((array) $body), true);
        $test = simplexml_load_string($simpleXml['qdeinvokeResponse']['qdereturn']['ns1data']);
        return json_decode(json_encode((array) $test), true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xml2jsonphp/

Or

simply,

`$json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xmlString));
$array = json_decode($json,true);`